# Is It Possible to Create Global Action on Chatter Object?

Tags: chatter, case

On Chatter Object,I can currently see 4 actions.

1. Post
2. Inquiry
3. New Event
4. New Task

I want to create Custom Action '**Create Case**' that allows me to create Case from Chatter Object.

I want to confirm if it is possible as I can not see Chatter Object while creating Global Action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce has already provided Global Action for 'Create Case'.We need to enable it on Global Publisher Layout.

1. Goto Setup-->Global Actions-->Publisher Layouts
2. Under Publisher Layout,Edit 'TrialForce Global Chatter' Layout and
   add the action.

Global Action will be visible in Chatter Object for Classic UI. However for Lightning, it will be visible in Lightning Global Action(+ Sign) not in Chatter Object.